# Can a cat/kitten suddenly stop liking her litter?

Tags: cats, behavior, cat-litter

This question goes hand in hand with my other, open thread:
[Kitten stopped using litter tray after having had diarrhea](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/29077/kitten-stopped-using-litter-tray-after-having-had-diarrhea)

Is it possible for a cat to suddenly stop liking a specific type of litter, that she used before?

Comment: Sudden dislike for a litter that wasn't a problem before can be a result of the cat associating trauma or pain with the litter, e.g. the cat might have had an injury to the paw, causing pain while digging in the box. It is possible the cat then associates that pain with the litter. In any case, one should keep a close eye on sudden changes in defecating behavior with cats. If in doubt, especially when the cat stops defecating entirely, one should consult a vet right away. Most vets will consult on the phone for free, and give guidance how to proceed, or if a visit is necessary.

Comment: As mentioned in my other post, the cat had diarrhea, which i think was because of the new food i started giving her. That being said, it crossed my mind that she might started associating diarrhea with the litter tray, and that's why she decided to not use it. What do you think?